# Python Script from Docx to CSV is escaping hyperlinked text

Tags: python-3.x

I am having a python Script that takes a word doc and gives back a CSV file. The word doc has some hyperlinked text, my python script escapes them and does not display them in the CSV file. What should I do to make him recognize the hyperlinked text as a plain text?

Comment: could you post the relevant part of the code as minimal reproducible example?

Comment: for table in tables[:]:
        for i, row in enumerate(table.rows[:]): # read each row
            row_content = []
            for cell in row.cells[:]: # read all cells in a row
                    c = cell.text
                    row_content.append(c.strip("\n"))
            data.append(row_content)
            print(data)

Comment: In your code you're reading from a table. Is this table parsed from your word doc? or did you mean excel? Besides you're printing to console and not in a csv... The code doesn't match the text of your question. Please edit your question with more context.

Comment: It would be helpful if you post a snippet of your code.